# SQL subqueries to laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, subquery

i have tried to pass one query to laravel but i can not do it. This  is the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM installations 
WHERE id = 1 AND
(SELECT eliminado from projects where id = installations.project_id) = 0;
```

I have tried things like

```
$project = installations::where([
          ['id',$id],
          [function ($query) use ($projects) {
              $query -> select('eliminado')
                     -> from('projects')
                     -> where('id', $projects[0]->project_id);
            }, 0]])->get();
```

OR

```
$projects =  DB::table('installations')
        ->select('*')
        ->where([
          ['id', 'LIKE', $id],
          [(function($query) use ($projects) {
            $query -> select('*')
                   -> from('projects')
                   -> where('id', $projects[0]->project_id);
            }), 'LIKE', '0']
          ])
    ->get();
```

But it still not working..., someone can help me with it? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use something like this :

```
$project = installations::where('id', $id)
      ->whereRaw('(SELECT eliminado from projects where id = installations.project_id) = ?', [0])
      ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the relation `project` on your `Installation` Model, you can do it like this.

```php
$intallation = Installation::whereHas('project', function($query) {
    $query->where('eliminado', '=', 0);
})->find($id);
```

The `project` relation should be a `belongsTo`.

**Intallation.php**

```php
public function project()
{
    $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this..

```
SELECT * 
FROM installations ins
WHERE id = 1 AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1 from projects p where p.id = ins.project_id AND p.eliminado =0);
```